# Manual scaling of color gradient with scale_color_gradientn() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to apply a color gradient of three colors (i.e., green, black, red) on a line in R.

**Sample Code**

```
# Create sample dataframe
df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 15 , 0.001), 
                 y = seq(0, 15, 0.001))

# Plot data
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, col = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("green", "black", "red"), 
                        values = rescale(x = c(0, 2, 4), to = c(0,1), from = c(0, 15) ))
```

[image]

**Question**

Using the `scale_color_gradientn()` function, I can apply a color gradient on the line. 
I would like to use green for values between 0 and 1.5, black for values between 1.5-2.5, and red for 2.5 and up, but I can't seem to grasp the `rescale()` function. In the example, the color stops at a y-value of 4.

How can I apply the color gradient in the desired way?

Comment: I think you need to append another `"red"` to the colours and use `x = c(0, 2, 4, 15)` in the rescale function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you provided no value/colour pair for the upper limit of the colour scale, these got interpreted as NAs and became gray. Fixing this should be as easy as providing the upper limit too.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
#> Warning: package 'scales' was built under R version 3.6.3

df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 15 , 0.001), 
                 y = seq(0, 15, 0.001))

# Plot data
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, col = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("green", "black", "red", "red"), 
                        values = rescale(x = c(0, 2, 4, 15), from = c(0, 15)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>